# Xcode ошибка расположения элемента в iOS приложении

Tags: ios, xcode

При выставлении текста (`Label` или `Button`) в конструкторе `Main.storyboard`, выдает ошибку

```
Views without any layout constraints may clip their content or overlap other views.
```

Как я понимаю нужно закрепить элемент что бы он не сдвигался на других устройствах, но как?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ознакомьтесь с темой [Auto Layout](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/AutolayoutPG/index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40010853-CH7-SW1) и применяйте эту систему для описания правил взаимного расположения элементов